# Android Studio: illegal start of type

Tags: java, android-studio

When I build my project, the error "illegal start of type" pop ..

I suppose the line who creates problem is the last `Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Everything works excepts this

Thanks

MainActivity

```
package com.example.pilotage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT = 1;

    TextView mStatusBlueTV, mPairedTV;
    ImageView mBlueIv;
    Button mONBtn, mOffBtn, mDiscoverBtn, mPairedBtn;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStatusBlueTV = findViewById(R.id.statusBluetoothTv);
        mPairedTV = findViewById(R.id.pairedTv);
        mBlueIv = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothIv);
        mONBtn = findViewById(R.id.onBtn);
        mOffBtn = findViewById(R.id.offBtn);
        mDiscoverBtn = findViewById(R.id.discoverableBtn);
        mPairedBtn = findViewById(R.id.pairedBtn);

        //adapteur
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //vérifier si le bluetooth est activé ou non
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            mStatusBlueTV.setText("Le Bluetooth n'est pas activé");
        }
        else {
            mStatusBlueTV.setText("Le Bluetooth est activé");
        }

        //accorder l'image selon si le bluetooth est activé ou non
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_on);
        }
        else {
            mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_off);
        }

        //Activer le bluetooth via l'appui sur le bouton
        mONBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mise en route du Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //intent to on bluetooth
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le bluetooth est déjà activé.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //discover bluetooth btn click
        mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Votre apapreil est devenu visible par les autres ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT);
                }
            }
        });
        //off btn click
        mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Désactivation du Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_off);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le Bluetooth est déjà désactivé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //get paired devices btn click
        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                    mPairedTV.setText("Paired Devices");
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    for (BluetoothDevice device: devices){
                        mPairedTV.append("\nDevice: " + device.getName()+ ", " + device);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //bluetooth is off so can't get paired devices
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activez le bluetooth pour obtenir des appareils", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                switch (requestCode){
                    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                            //bluetooth is on
                            mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_on);
                            showToast("Le Bluetooth est activé");
                        }
                        else {
                            //user denied to turn bluetooth on
                            showToast("Le Bluetooth ne peut pas être mit en route");
                        }
                        break;
                }
                MainActivity.super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }

            //toast message function
            private void showToast(String msg){
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: is this compile time or runtime issue? can you post full error stack? why do you use `showToast ` only in `onActivityResult `?

Comment: It's when i compile the project and i use showToast only in onActivityResult because it's a test and th only place it works

Comment: @LisePilato `showToast` method looks fine and it should work everywhere inside the Activity class. Where does constant `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT` come from? You should debug it and check if this line is correct: `mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_on);`. 
`R.drawable.ic_action_on` might contain some illegal expression

Comment: @pavle check the `{` and the `}`. Some things are in the wrong blocks. The `showToast` method is inside the `onClickListener`

Comment: @Nizar but why? so, you're passing `this` to `show` method. `show` expects `Context` but you are passing `View.OnClickListener`. `showToast` should be in `Activity` class, or you should use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activez le bluetooth pour obtenir des appareils", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` that you already use. I am not sure what is your goal with this to be honest?

Comment: @pavle my whole goal is to point out that her errors are due to wrong code formatting. Check what I mentioned in my answer. Try copying her code and pasting it and checking the start and end of each block. Then you'll understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains missing `braces {}` and misplaced `parenthesis ()`.

> Instead of closing `mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {});` correctly, you included `onActivityResult` and `showToast` inside the `onClickListener`. Which lead to the missing `onCreate` and `Class` `braces {}`.

```java
package com.example.pilotage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT = 1;

    TextView mStatusBlueTV, mPairedTV;
    ImageView mBlueIv;
    Button mONBtn, mOffBtn, mDiscoverBtn, mPairedBtn;

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStatusBlueTV = findViewById(R.id.statusBluetoothTv);
        mPairedTV = findViewById(R.id.pairedTv);
        mBlueIv = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothIv);
        mONBtn = findViewById(R.id.onBtn);
        mOffBtn = findViewById(R.id.offBtn);
        mDiscoverBtn = findViewById(R.id.discoverableBtn);
        mPairedBtn = findViewById(R.id.pairedBtn);

        //adapteur
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //vérifier si le bluetooth est activé ou non
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            mStatusBlueTV.setText("Le Bluetooth n'est pas activé");
        } else {
            mStatusBlueTV.setText("Le Bluetooth est activé");
        }

        //accorder l'image selon si le bluetooth est activé ou non
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_on);
        } else {
            mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_off);
        }

        //Activer le bluetooth via l'appui sur le bouton
        mONBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mise en route du Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //intent to on bluetooth
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le bluetooth est déjà activé.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        //discover bluetooth btn click
        mDiscoverBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Votre apapreil est devenu visible par les autres ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVER_BT);
                }
            }
        });
        //off btn click
        mOffBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Désactivation du Bluetooth...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_off);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Le Bluetooth est déjà désactivé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        //get paired devices btn click
        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mPairedTV.setText("Paired Devices");
                    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                        mPairedTV.append("\nDevice: " + device.getName() + ", " + device);
                    }
                } else {
                    //bluetooth is off so can't get paired devices
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activez le bluetooth pour obtenir des appareils", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //bluetooth is on
                    mBlueIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_on);
                    showToast("Le Bluetooth est activé");
                } else {
                    //user denied to turn bluetooth on
                    showToast("Le Bluetooth ne peut pas être mit en route");
                }
                break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //toast message function
    private void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have other buttons, so i must repeat the OnActivityResult and le private showToast in the OnClickListener for each button ?

Comment: No, no, the `onActivityResult` and the `showToast` must be in the whole `Class` not inside the `onClickListener` and not inside the `onCreate`. I fixed your code, you can check it out, and you'll understand what I mean